# Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer (layer 7) for GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am having trouble using the HTTP Load Balancer (Layer 7) with a service in GKE. I originally exposed the service in GKE using the LoadBalancer service type:

kubectl expose deployment myservice --type="LoadBalancer"

This will create a public IP address for my cluster in the same zone and it has been working well. My goal is to use a global IP address with SSL support for my service. This is what I have tried:

1. expose the GKE service as NodePort type
   kubectl expose deployment myservice --type=“NodeType”
2. follow the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) to create an ingress object. It didn’t work because the service in GKE is already in a managed instance group, and the ingress object would create a new instance group with zero instance. I found a discussion [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes/issues/49).
3. follow the suggestion in the discussion. Deleted to ingress object, and try to set up the HTTP Load Balancer manually from google cloud console.

   - Added a firewall rules to allow 130.211.0.0/22 on port 80 and 8081 (my service port) on all targets.
   - Backend service is the managed Instance group created by GKE.
   - Created a health check on port 8081, path /health.
     It still doesn’t work because the load balancer can recognize the correct number of instances in the managed instance group, but there are zero healthy nodes. My service has a health check endpoint myservice:8081/health and the root path "/" also returns HTTP 200 OK. I played with the health check configurations but the load balancer can never find a healthy node.

What am I missing?

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way to go about this is:   
1. Create a deployment with an nginx server, where you can configure your SSL connection. It will route the requests to your other services.   
2. Create a service of a type LoadBalancer around the nginx    deployment, which will give you a public IP.

Comment: That might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136891/gcloud-ingress-loadbalancer-static-ip. If you use ingresses and start using kube-lego (in case letsencrypt is enough), you'd be surprised about how easy it all become

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if I want to follow the ingress tutorial, I cannot define a HTTP(S) Load Balancer on the same endpoint. You either choose to follow the tutorial and let the ingress object to define a LB automatically, which worked for me after deleting my testing LB, or do not use ingress and define LB manually (which I never got it working).