# Google Cloud Ingress: Use Regional IP from other region for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

we are currently still running our Kubernetes cluster in region `europe-west2` (London) but have to use a new ipaddress for an ingress on the cluster from `europe-west3` (Frankfurt).

After trying to deploy our new ingress on the cluster in region `europe-west2` I get the following error:

```
the given static IP name xyz doesn't translate to an existing static IP.
```

I assume that ingress only has access to regional IP addresses in the same region.

I use the following annotation:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: xyz
```

Does anybody have an idea how to use the IP address from `europe-west3` on an ingress in  `europe-west2`?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your issue but couldn't find any solution.

However, note that from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#use_an_ingress):

> Regional IP addresses do not work with Ingress.
>
> To learn more about how to use Ingress to expose your applications to the internet, refer to the Setting up HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress tutorial.

And please refer to the similar issues and the useful answers under it:

- [Issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257182/16860542)
- [Issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164860/16860542)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor We decided to use an nginx-ingress which allowed us to use a regional IP.